# What is a good sound board to use for doing real time active noise reduction on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, audio, audio-playback

I'm doing a project that involves making a pair of headphones capable of active noise reduction.  Specifically, I'm attempting to do impulse based noise reduction rather than blocking a constant repeating sound.  I'll be programming in C++, and planned to use a Raspberry Pi, however it seems I would need a separate board for audio processing.  Does anyone have any recommendations for what to use here, or possibly a better method than the Pi + sound board?  I don't know a whole lot about audio processing or the hardware involved, so any knowledge shared is appreciated.

I am aware of the delays that using a Pi would likely introduce, however getting around those is part of the project's focus and I have some solutions in mind, but suggestions are also appreciated in this area.

Answer (score 1):

There is an incomplete short list of sound cards available [here on eLinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound)

You will most likely want to use a GPIO board rather then a USB sound card because of the USB latency issues.

I think you can get latencies as low as 1ms or less in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guy on YouTube named John Darko I believe that a addressed this in an episode. I bought a Schitt DAC per his recommendation but he does mention one that you can attach as a HAT because the power is noisy. He rigged it to run with batteries and it was much cleaner. https://www.allo.com/

Comment: Do you have a link? Please edit your answer and add the link.